# Bash in Jupyter Notebook: 'SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character'

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to download some data using a bash script in a Jupyter notebook and having some problems.

I added quotes to the file paths after I received a 'SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character' error.

However, I'm stumped on how to fix the same error on the Wget command.

This is the contents of the cell as I have it now.

```
%%bash

FILE=apple2orange

URL="https\://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~taesung_park/CycleGAN/datasets/$FILE.zip"
ZIP_FILE="./datasets/$FILE.zip"
TARGET_DIR="./datasets/$FILE/"
wget -N \$URL -O \$ZIP_FILE
mkdir $TARGET_DIR
unzip $ZIP_FILE -d ./datasets/
rm $ZIP_FILE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed a little on your script. Now it looks like this:

```sh
%%bash

FILE=apple2orange

URL="https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~taesung_park/CycleGAN/datasets/$FILE.zip"
ZIP_FILE="./datasets/$FILE.zip"
TARGET_DIR="./datasets/$FILE/"
mkdir -p $TARGET_DIR
wget -N $URL -O $ZIP_FILE
unzip $ZIP_FILE -d ./datasets/
rm $ZIP_FILE
```

In `bash` strings `:` doesn't need to be escaped. That was the error I think.
It works on my end.

Have a try.